# How to retrieve all values from a foreach loop C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am developing a JavaScript calendar based system to display dates for events in .Net Core and the issue I am having is iterating through the foreach loop and the last value is the only value that is displaying on my calendar , controller code as follows:

```
    public IActionResult Calendar()
    {
        var dateList = _context.Tasks.Select(x => x.DateAllTaskCompleted != null ? x.DateAllTaskCompleted.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null).ToList();
        var jsonDate="";

        foreach (var item in dateList)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                // TODO: Display all dates

                jsonDate = JsonSerializer.Serialize(item);
            }
        }
        ViewData["Date"] = jsonDate;

        return View();
    }
```

What solutions or adjustments can I make ?

Comment: Every time your loop iterates, you overwrite the previous value of `jsonDate`. Perhaps creating a list of strings, which you can then add to, would solve your problem? 
For example: 
`var jsonDateList = new List<string>();`

and

`jsonDateList.add(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are overriding `jsonDate` in each loop iteration. If you want to retrieve all dates you will need to declare, for example, `jsonDates` as list, and then to append to list in each iteration. Something like this:

```
public IActionResult Calendar()
{
    var dateList = _context.Tasks.Select(x => x.DateAllTaskCompleted != null ? x.DateAllTaskCompleted.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null).ToList();
    List<string> jsonDates = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in dateList)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            // TODO: Display all dates

            jsonDates.Add(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item));
        }
    }
    ViewData["Date"] = jsonDates;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: thank you , I have implemented the solution.